# How to access main of iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs

I have created one iFrame window and in that there is separate ext app.

```
Win = new Ext.IframeWindow({
                        id: 'MyWinID',
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        title: 'H1',
                        closable: true,
                        constrain : true,
                    });
    Win.width = (winWidth / 100) * 90,
    Win.height = (winHeight / 100) * 90,
    Win.show().center();
```

On the resize I wanted to access the app which is placed in iFrame.

```
listeners :{
            resize : function(a,b,c){
                // How to access element of main at this point. I am trying this
                var WinFrame =  window.frames['MyWinID']
                }
            }
```

My main of iFrame app is

```
Ext.define('My.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
    ],

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: 'main',
    layout: 'border',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        frame: true,
        region: 'south',
        items: [ some item]
    },
    {
        title: 'App',
        itemId: 'selectionPanel',
        region: 'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        scroll: 'y',
        frame: true,
         items: []
    },
    {
        xtype: 'panel',    
        region: 'center',
        frame: true,
        scrollable: true,
        scroll: 'y',    
        itemId: 'abc',
        reference: 'abc',
        layout: {
            //type: 'anchor',
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: []
    }]
});
```

Can you please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript basic rule:

> "global" variables (e.g. `Ext`) are available in the tree under `window` and vice versa, so `window.Ext.getCmp("MyWinID")` and `Ext.getCmp("MyWinID")` are the same.

Javascript rule for frames:

> `window.frames[id]` contains the selected frame's `window` element.

Both together yield the answer your question, which can be summarized in this simple example:

```
window.frames['MyAppFrame'].Ext.getCmp("MyTestContainer").add({
    xtype:'button',
    handler:function(btn) {
        btn.up('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: window.Ext.getCmp("MyWinID")  this part I understood and I used in my listener but how to use  `Ext.getCmp("MyTestContainer)` because you can see in my main I need to access one of the item of the main. I able to access window but then not able to access any of the items in window

Comment: Also by using `window.frames['MyID']` I am getting some html and div component and in that after opening div I am getting iframe as a tag. How to access that.

Comment: @David You can go into Sencha fiddle and test. The fiddle is running in an iframe. `window.frames[0].Ext` gives you the fiddle's `Ext` object from browser console. Not sure what exactly you are doing differently in your code...

Comment: THanks. It helped me lot